# How can I re-populate a view model from deserialized json?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My ViewModel class is a statically defined in my App.xaml.cs like this so I have access to it all over the app.

```
public static ViewModel.MainViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel.MainViewModel();
```

Using NewtonSoft JSON.Net library I serialize my View model (ignoring certain properties I didn't want to save) to a JSON string for saving to file like this:

```
var viewModelJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.viewModel,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

To load it back I open the text file and deserialize it like this:

```
var viewModel = (ViewModel.MainViewModel)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents, typeof(ViewModel.MainViewModel));
```

After deserializing I tried to replace the App.viewModel object with viewModel like this:

```
App.viewModel = viewModel;
```

...but all of the bindings disappear so I'm guessing you can't do that.

So my only solution so far is to go through each property and set them again one by one with saved values like this:

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();

                var viewModel = (ViewModel.MainViewModel)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents, typeof(ViewModel.MainViewModel));

                App.viewModel.telemetryFile = viewModel.telemetryFile;
                App.viewModel.producedOn = viewModel.producedOn;
                App.viewModel.analysisDate = viewModel.analysisDate;
                App.viewModel.systemID = viewModel.systemID;
                App.viewModel.from = viewModel.from;
                App.viewModel.through = viewModel.through;
                //etc
                //etc
            }
```

However I have many properties to set (not all listed here) so writing all those lines to repopulate the Viewmodel seems inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? (efficient for the programmer, because writing each line one by one to repopulate each property for a viewmodel with hundreds can be time consuming and prone to mistakes)

**EDIT**

As per suggestions in the comments I tried the following - added property to viewmodel:

```
    private MainViewModel _otherViewModel;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public MainViewModel otherViewModel
    {
        get { return _otherViewModel; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _otherViewModel, value);
        }
    }
```

In my View I set the data context to that property:

```
    public TelemetryReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.viewModel.otherViewModel;
    }
```

(left all my bindings the same in the XAML, properties inside never changed)
For example

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=telemetryFile, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Then in my other class where I open the file I did this:

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();

                var viewModel = (ViewModel.MainViewModel)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents, typeof(ViewModel.MainViewModel));

                App.viewModel.otherViewModel = viewModel;

            }
```

But nothing got updated on the view. Was it supposed to?

Comment: You would probably just assign the new viewModel object to the DataContext property of all your views.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency. Hiding all those assignments in a loop somewhere won't make it faster at runtime. I doubt that you've got a performance issue anyway. Also static viewmodel, bad idea.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I meant more about programmer efficiency, I thought there would be an easier way instead of setting them one by one.  For lots of properties it can be time consuming to code

Comment: @Clemens that's probably why the bindings didn't work on my first attempt, however the code where I am deserializing the vewmodel is located in another class, I don't have access to each datacontext from that location.

Comment: @erotavlas So write a main viewmodel that's shared around. Put the serialized stuff in a child viewmodel `OtherStuffVM` that's a property of the main viewmodel and raises `PropertyChanged` in the setter. Make the main vm a singleton if you insist, but replace the child as needed with a newly deserialized child vm. Have all the innumerable views bind to `OtherStuffVM.telemetryFile` or whatever. This is SOP and it works, no fooling around or clever stuff needed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. I think I would have to set the datacontext again after the object gets updated

Comment: @erotavlas Why do you think that? Do you generally find that you have to update the DataContext when any property of the viewmodel changes? What did you actually try? Code, please.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Done. See my edit.

Comment: Please do what I suggested instead. Use the mainviewmodel for the datacontexts, and in the views, bind to its properties. For example, like this: `<Label Content="{Binding otherViewModel.telemetryFile}" />`. mainviewmodel is the DataContext. `otherViewModel` is  a property of that DataContext. When mInviewmodel raises PropertyChanged to announce that otherViewModel has a new value, the Binding will update. How would you expect the BInding to update in response to an event from a viewmodel you never told it about?

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you, it works, much better than what I originally had and easier to maintain. :)

Comment: I would suggest to think about application design. IMHO, idea with static variables and serializing/deserializing view models looks a bit weird.

Comment: @Valerii regarding the deserializing/serializing view model do you have any other suggestion to improve this?  I feel like if I create a separate class to hold the data, then I need to do more work to transfer it to the viewmodel after opening it.

Comment: @erotavlas It depends on complexity of your project. It's hard to say how you can change it without seeing whole project. A assume that if you have load data from file you have something like OpenFileCommand. Is it part of your MainViewModel? Maybe it would be a good idea just not to think about data like it is a view model. Instead of OtherViewModel you can call it for example TelemertyData, implement INotifyPropertyChanged for this property and set it when you load data from file.

Comment: @Valerii yes command to open file and analyze it is in view model like this public ICommand openCommand { get; set; }  and in constructor created like this this.openCommand = new DelegatingCommand(_commandMethods.openCommand_execute, _commandMethods.openCommand_canExecute);  --- its a small project - open CSV file, load data into IEnumerable<DataRow> then perform LINQ queries to extract relevant information, based on your comment I decided to create a dedicated Data class to hold the data produced by the queries, instead of storing the results in the viewmodel directly

Comment: "I decided to create a dedicated Data class to hold the data produced by the queries, instead of storing the results in the viewmodel directly". I think in your case it will be a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with reflection, but there's a much better way. I suggest you split the serialized properties into a child viewmodel, and give the singleton main viewmodel a property of that type:

```
private ChildViewModel _childVM;
public ChildViewModel ChildVM {
    //  standard INotifyPropertyChanged property implementation
}
```

Your singleton main viewmodel will still be the DataContext for all the same views. But when you deserialize a new copy of ChildVM, instead of copying all those properties to raise all those PropertyChanged events, just assign the newly deserialized instance of `ChildViewModel` to `mainViewModel.ChildVM`.

In all the views, you'll now bind like so:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ChildVM.telemetryFile}" />
```

Where formerly, `telemetryFile` was a property of the main viewmodel, and that binding would have looked like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding telemetryFile}" />
```